# Mirror site with a funny name?

Tags: discussion, scraper-sites

I came across this site http://math.dingding.in/ while I was looking up a user online. I am just curious how the above link leads to the same site(I mean the web address seems a bit unconventional.)
Just curious.

Comment: [This meta.SE thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do) covers what to do in this situation; there are a lot of sites that copy the content of SE sites.